# What are the hidden Shortcuts in Swing Components?

Tags: java, swing, keyboard-shortcuts, hidden, shortcut

I found out <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> in my JTextPane changes the ComponentOrientation.

For my own TextEditor I have to disable this, but are there other Shortcuts in JTextPane or in other Swing-Components?

Keyboard bindings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> are known.
Are there more?

Comment: sry, this is the German `Ctrl`

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254637/how-do-i-stop-my-jtextpane-swallowing-keyboard-shortcuts-accelerators/3255444#3255444

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> but are there other Shortcuts in JTextPane or in other Swing-Components?

See [Key Bindings](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/10/key-bindings/) which lists all the bindings and shows how to disable a binding you don't want.

Comment: awesome +1 for exactly what I am looking for

Comment: @oliholz It sounds like this is the correct Answer - mark it as such please!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (I haven't checked it myself):

```
myTextPane.getKeymap().removeKeyStrokeBinding(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl shift O"));
```

That should remove the binding from that accelerator for `myTextPane`.

If you want to find all key bindings then just iterate through the `Keymap`:

```
for (KeyStroke stroke: myTextPane.getKeymap().getBoundKeyStrokes())
{
    Sytem.out.println(stroke.toString());
}
```

Note that you can also disable a given `KeyStroke` for all text components:

```
JTextComponent.getKeymap(JTextComponent.DEFAULT_KEYMAP).removeKeyStrokeBinding(
    KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl shift O"));
```

Because `JTextComponent.DEFAULT_KEYMAP` defines the name of the common `Keymap` used by default for every `JTextComponent` (including subclasses like `JTextPane`).

Comment: should work (didn't try either :) - but would suggest to not use keyMaps, they are legacy and internally wrapped into InputMaps (leaning far out off the open window in the fifth floor, should _really_ check ;-)

Comment: -1, although the solution will probably work, we should be promoting the newer API and programming practices. Keymaps where replaced in JDK1.3 by Key Bindings. See: http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html

Comment: @camickr Granted, but it is good to mention that the javadoc for JTextComponent doesn't say _anything_ about Keymap being deprecated or replaced with key bindings. It doesn't even mention ActionMap/InputMap. When reading the javadoc I was even wondering if working directly with InputMap would work for this issue (I haven't tried it)!

Comment: @camickr That report is gone from the URL. Luckily, it was captured by the Wayback Machine: [snapshot](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230135154/http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/special_report/kestrel/keybindings.html). Doing a few searches suggests that this might be the only surviving copy of it visible to the public.